# An update button?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I was wandering if you want to know the activities of a specific question which is not yours (like < xyz> did a comment and < abc> gave an answer) there should be a button like `send you updates of this question ?` which sends updates of your chosen **question** and **answer**.

**EDIT** : I wanted to get updates in user's inbox !

Comment: Yes, it's called Favourites, and you activate it for a question by clicking the star below the voting buttons.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, I think favourites only go half-way, because they don't give notifications in the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

Every question has its own [Atom feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29). Look for a link called "question feed" down there ↘ somewhere. If you have a newsreader like Apple Mail, you can subscribe to this feed with a simple drag & drop operation.

For example, [here's the feed for this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/1275). See if you can get your computer to do something useful with it.

Answer (score 1):

### This now exists in the form of [following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/355458)

You are, as of March 2020, able to "follow" any post - question or answer - on any site. From the linked Mother Meta post:

> [Y]ou will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices. You will not receive notifications for any action that you performed